# Links in drop-down menu not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The links in the "on sale" section of each of the top tab drop-downs on [this website](http://dev.braceshop.com) do not work at all in IE. Any ideas?

Comment: Could the `filter` properties (served to IE by conditionnal comments) be the source of the problem?

Comment: Hi Felipe,

It's the conditional filters! Removing them makes the links work fine. Now to see what's broken with them gone.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest running this through the W3C markup validator as you have a number of invalid XHTML elements. I think the culprit may be an 's' element in your On Sale div. That element is deprecated - you should use the 'del' instead for strikethrough. There are also a couple of places where you're setting the display attribute to 'hidden' when you should be setting it to 'none'.

Comment: Hi Jim,

What should we use instead? It didn't come through on here. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Sorry, had to fix my comment to be compatible with stack overflow's rendering. Be sure to run the W3C validator on your page. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.braceshop.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0